# Jinja2: how to check if input is hidden

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have the following stardard render code:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <div class="control-group"> 
        <div class="controls">
            {% if not field.hidden %}
                {{ field.label }}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

And for hidden field I do not want label to appear.

But the HTML result I got is:

```
  <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label for="foo">Foo</label>   <-- why this did not go?
            <input id="foo" name="foo" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Am I wrong saying " if not field.hidden ", what is the right way of checking this?

And I am not talking here about CSRF token.

Comment: No, it's not about that special CSRF hidden field

Comment: The accepted answer contains a solution for all hidden fields, not just CSRF.

Answer (score 0):

WTForm

foo = HiddenField('email',[])

on HTML page

Use `field.foo.hidden`

Comment: field.email.hidden does not seem to work I am afraid